# How to replace text on an click event using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here when i click on a particular player its score is displayed.But when again a player is clicked the previous score doesn't get cleared.So pls can anyone provide the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        $("#sidebar").append("<div id=" + i + " class='player'>" + temp[i].name + "</div>")

    $(".player").click(function () {
        var pla = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#score").append(temp[pla].score);

        //$(".content").append(a[pla].Events);

        var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");
        var a = $("span").append($(this).text());

        $(".player").removeClass("highlight");
        if (!selected) {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            $(this.Text()).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: would be great if you can share the markup as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to add a call to `.html()` for the sidebar to clear its content, add it at the top of your document ready function.

So something like:

```
$("#sidebar").html();
```

Comment: No dats not working.                                $("#score").append(temp[pla].score);    I am using this to append the score .But it is not  removing the previous score when i click on another div

Comment: [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) adds content on to the end of the selector, so it will never clear what's already there, it will just add to it. Maybe try and use `.html()` instead of .append. Not sure I can offer more help without seeing the html as [Milind Anantwar](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1719752/milind-anantwar) suggested.